# How to get custom field unserialized (get advanced custom fields in rest api)?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following json response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 128537,
    "date": "2019-06-28T09:41:50",
    "date_gmt": "2019-06-28T09:41:50",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://example.com/ing2/?p=128537"
    },
    "modified": "2019-07-11T14:12:47",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-07-11T14:12:47",
    "slug": "villa-ortobene",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa-ortobene/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Villa Ortobene"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "",
      "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
      626,
      520
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "details": {
      "_edit_last": [
        "1"
      ],
      "_edit_lock": [
        "1562854460:1"
      ],
      "descrizione_lavoro": [
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum magna eu neque sodales semper. Nulla eget purus turpis. Nulla ut pretium nulla. Mauris nec massa ac risus convallis aliquam vitae ac dolor. Cras eget leo quis massa auctor dignissim ut mollis tellus. Curabitur sollicitudin diam nisl, sed molestie mi finibus in.\r\n\r\nInterdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer feugiat, mi eget varius aliquam, mauris diam interdum mauris, ac lobortis risus velit eu mauris.\r\n\r\nNulla vehicula felis bibendum facilisis dignissim. Morbi consequat a nisl ac pulvinar. Donec tempor tellus et urna rutrum, et pharetra est accumsan. Morbi porttitor et lectus vel convallis. Vivamus quam leo, maximus sed placerat eu, facilisis a lectus. Sed mollis sapien mollis egestas ullamcorper. Proin eu velit quis ex volutpat convallis. Vivamus dolor dui, scelerisque bibendum ligula in, fermentum ultricies lorem.\r\n\r\nVestibulum porttitor nulla in mattis porta. Integer lobortis rhoncus dolor placerat aliquam. Praesent interdum dui vitae tortor varius tincidunt. Ut efficitur egestas libero, sed gravida dolor gravida quis. Aenean lacinia, neque eu feugiat dictum, felis libero dignissim elit, eget laoreet purus odio in velit. Suspendisse massa nibh, pharetra aliquam risus eget, ultricies semper purus."
      ],
      "_descrizione_lavoro": [
        "field_5d1370af6f74d"
      ],
      "location": [
        "a:3:{s:7:\"address\";s:95:\"Avinguda de la Granvia de l’Hospitalet, 8, 08902 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat, Barcelona, Spagna\";s:3:\"lat\";s:17:\"41.36256133817761\";s:3:\"lng\";s:17:\"2.131976960327165\";}"
      ],
      "_location": [
        "field_5d12254915703"
      ],
      "quando": [
        "2016"
      ],
      "_quando": [
        "field_5d18cee430b4e"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "a:1:{i:0;s:3:\"627\";}"
      ],
      "_categories": [
        "field_5d1226f4d6974"
      ],
      "partner": [
        "a:1:{i:0;s:13:\"Sandra Yannis\";}"
      ],
      "_partner": [
        "field_5d124f89a4906"
      ],
      "collaboratori": [
        "a:2:{i:0;s:10:\"Fran White\";i:1;s:10:\"Sam Jumper\";}"
      ],
      "_collaboratori": [
        "field_5d13736937e7f"
      ],
      "importo": [
        "1200000"
      ],
      "_importo": [
        "field_5d1227e726e32"
      ],
      "galleria": [
        "a:4:{i:0;s:6:\"128345\";i:1;s:6:\"128346\";i:2;s:6:\"128344\";i:3;s:6:\"128343\";}"
      ],
      "_galleria": [
        "field_5d135d5440503"
      ],
      "home_immagine": [
        "128542"
      ],
      "_home_immagine": [
        "field_5c7c00fdec7f7"
      ],
      "progetti_preview": [
        "128540"
      ],
      "_progetti_preview": [
        "field_5c7c04c5b54a4"
      ],
      "codice_lavoro": [
        "0F122"
      ],
      "_codice_lavoro": [
        "field_5d122a75f0cc2"
      ],
      "id_opera": [
        "EG09"
      ],
      "_id_opera": [
        "field_5d137a87bddeb"
      ],
      "tipologia": [
        ""
      ],
      "_tipologia": [
        "field_5d137a998884f"
      ],
      "assegna_le_categorie_0_nome_categoria": [
        "Ingegneria"
      ],
      "_assegna_le_categorie_0_nome_categoria": [
        "field_5d14a7895ac17"
      ],
      "assegna_le_categorie_0_costo": [
        "275000"
      ],
      "_assegna_le_categorie_0_costo": [
        "field_5d14a79d5ac18"
      ],
      "assegna_le_categorie": [
        "2"
      ],
      "_assegna_le_categorie": [
        "field_5d14a76d5ac16"
      ],
      "tipologia_lavoro": [
        "A01"
      ],
      "_tipologia_lavoro": [
        "field_5d137a998884f"
      ],
      "il_committente": [
        "a:1:{i:0;s:17:\"Comune di sassari\";}"
      ],
      "_il_committente": [
        "field_5d1628244adfa"
      ],
      "status": [
        "In corso"
      ],
      "_status": [
        "field_5d162ba7fb989"
      ],
      "servizi": [
        "a:1:{i:0;s:13:\"Progettazione\";}"
      ],
      "_servizi": [
        "field_5d162cbaa4a2d"
      ],
      "assegna_le_categorie_1_nome_categoria": [
        "Edilizia"
      ],
      "_assegna_le_categorie_1_nome_categoria": [
        "field_5d14a7895ac17"
      ],
      "assegna_le_categorie_1_costo": [
        "328000"
      ],
      "_assegna_le_categorie_1_costo": [
        "field_5d14a79d5ac18"
      ],
      "anno": [
        "2015"
      ],
      "_anno": [
        "field_5d18cee430b4e"
      ],
      "mese": [
        "1"
      ],
      "_mese": [
        "field_5d18fee45fd32"
      ],
      "_wp_old_slug": [
        "villa-ortobene__trashed"
      ],
      "latitude": [
        "41.36256133817761"
      ],
      "longitude": [
        "2.131976960327165"
      ]
    },
    "acf": {
      "descrizione_lavoro": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum magna eu neque sodales semper. Nulla eget purus turpis. Nulla ut pretium nulla. Mauris nec massa ac risus convallis aliquam vitae ac dolor. Cras eget leo quis massa auctor dignissim ut mollis tellus. Curabitur sollicitudin diam nisl, sed molestie mi finibus in.</p>\n<p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer feugiat, mi eget varius aliquam, mauris diam interdum mauris, ac lobortis risus velit eu mauris.</p>\n<p>Nulla vehicula felis bibendum facilisis dignissim. Morbi consequat a nisl ac pulvinar. Donec tempor tellus et urna rutrum, et pharetra est accumsan. Morbi porttitor et lectus vel convallis. Vivamus quam leo, maximus sed placerat eu, facilisis a lectus. Sed mollis sapien mollis egestas ullamcorper. Proin eu velit quis ex volutpat convallis. Vivamus dolor dui, scelerisque bibendum ligula in, fermentum ultricies lorem.</p>\n<p>Vestibulum porttitor nulla in mattis porta. Integer lobortis rhoncus dolor placerat aliquam. Praesent interdum dui vitae tortor varius tincidunt. Ut efficitur egestas libero, sed gravida dolor gravida quis. Aenean lacinia, neque eu feugiat dictum, felis libero dignissim elit, eget laoreet purus odio in velit. Suspendisse massa nibh, pharetra aliquam risus eget, ultricies semper purus.</p>\n",
      "location": {
        "address": "Avinguda de la Granvia de l’Hospitalet, 8, 08902 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat, Barcelona, Spagna",
        "lat": "41.36256133817761",
        "lng": "2.131976960327165"
      },
      "categories": [
        627
      ],
      "partner": [
        "Sandra Yannis"
      ],
      "collaboratori": [
        "Fran White",
        "Sam Jumper"
      ],
      "importo": "1200000",
      "galleria": [
        {
          "ID": 128345,
          "id": 128345,
          "title": "villa1",
          "filename": "villa1.jpg",
          "filesize": 78350,
          "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa1.jpg",
          "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa1/",
          "alt": "",
          "author": "1",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "name": "villa1",
          "status": "inherit",
          "uploaded_to": 0,
          "date": "2019-03-05 11:43:03",
          "modified": "2019-03-05 11:43:03",
          "menu_order": 0,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "subtype": "jpeg",
          "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 667,
          "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa1-150x150.jpg",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa1-280x187.jpg",
            "medium-width": 280,
            "medium-height": 187,
            "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa1-768x512.jpg",
            "medium_large-width": 768,
            "medium_large-height": 512,
            "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa1.jpg",
            "large-width": "1000",
            "large-height": "667"
          }
        },
        {
          "ID": 128346,
          "id": 128346,
          "title": "villa2",
          "filename": "villa2.jpg",
          "filesize": 55980,
          "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2.jpg",
          "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa2/",
          "alt": "",
          "author": "1",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "name": "villa2",
          "status": "inherit",
          "uploaded_to": 0,
          "date": "2019-03-05 11:43:04",
          "modified": "2019-04-03 12:07:52",
          "menu_order": 0,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "subtype": "jpeg",
          "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 667,
          "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2-150x150.jpg",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2-280x187.jpg",
            "medium-width": 280,
            "medium-height": 187,
            "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2-768x512.jpg",
            "medium_large-width": 768,
            "medium_large-height": 512,
            "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2.jpg",
            "large-width": "1000",
            "large-height": "667"
          }
        },
        {
          "ID": 128344,
          "id": 128344,
          "title": "villa3",
          "filename": "villa3.jpg",
          "filesize": 67396,
          "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa3.jpg",
          "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa3/",
          "alt": "",
          "author": "1",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "name": "villa3",
          "status": "inherit",
          "uploaded_to": 0,
          "date": "2019-03-05 11:41:49",
          "modified": "2019-03-05 11:41:49",
          "menu_order": 0,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "subtype": "jpeg",
          "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
          "width": 744,
          "height": 445,
          "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa3-150x150.jpg",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa3-313x187.jpg",
            "medium-width": 313,
            "medium-height": 187,
            "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa3.jpg",
            "medium_large-width": 744,
            "medium_large-height": 445,
            "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa3.jpg",
            "large-width": "744",
            "large-height": "445"
          }
        },
        {
          "ID": 128343,
          "id": 128343,
          "title": "villa4",
          "filename": "villa4.jpg",
          "filesize": 93285,
          "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa4.jpg",
          "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa4/",
          "alt": "",
          "author": "1",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "name": "villa4",
          "status": "inherit",
          "uploaded_to": 0,
          "date": "2019-03-05 11:41:48",
          "modified": "2019-03-05 11:41:48",
          "menu_order": 0,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "subtype": "jpeg",
          "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 743,
          "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa4-150x150.jpg",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa4-252x187.jpg",
            "medium-width": 252,
            "medium-height": 187,
            "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa4-768x571.jpg",
            "medium_large-width": 768,
            "medium_large-height": 571,
            "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa4.jpg",
            "large-width": "1000",
            "large-height": "743"
          }
        }
      ],
      "home_immagine": {
        "ID": 128542,
        "id": 128542,
        "title": "villa2-aspect-ratio-x",
        "filename": "villa2-aspect-ratio-x-3.jpg",
        "filesize": 48677,
        "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/villa2-aspect-ratio-x-3.jpg",
        "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa-ortobene/villa2-aspect-ratio-x-4/",
        "alt": "",
        "author": "1",
        "description": "",
        "caption": "",
        "name": "villa2-aspect-ratio-x-4",
        "status": "inherit",
        "uploaded_to": 128537,
        "date": "2019-06-28 09:45:34",
        "modified": "2019-06-28 09:45:40",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "image",
        "subtype": "jpeg",
        "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 429,
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/villa2-aspect-ratio-x-3-150x150.jpg",
          "thumbnail-width": 150,
          "thumbnail-height": 150,
          "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/villa2-aspect-ratio-x-3-436x187.jpg",
          "medium-width": 436,
          "medium-height": 187,
          "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/villa2-aspect-ratio-x-3-768x329.jpg",
          "medium_large-width": 768,
          "medium_large-height": 329,
          "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/villa2-aspect-ratio-x-3.jpg",
          "large-width": "1000",
          "large-height": "429"
        },
        "original_image": {
          "ID": 128346,
          "id": 128346,
          "title": "villa2",
          "filename": "villa2.jpg",
          "filesize": 55980,
          "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2.jpg",
          "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa2/",
          "alt": "",
          "author": "1",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "name": "villa2",
          "status": "inherit",
          "uploaded_to": 0,
          "date": "2019-03-05 11:43:04",
          "modified": "2019-04-03 12:07:52",
          "menu_order": 0,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "subtype": "jpeg",
          "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 667,
          "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2-150x150.jpg",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2-280x187.jpg",
            "medium-width": 280,
            "medium-height": 187,
            "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2-768x512.jpg",
            "medium_large-width": 768,
            "medium_large-height": 512,
            "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/villa2.jpg",
            "large-width": "1000",
            "large-height": "667"
          }
        }
      },
      "progetti_preview": {
        "ID": 128540,
        "id": 128540,
        "title": "2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x",
        "filename": "2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x.jpg",
        "filesize": 22343,
        "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x.jpg",
        "link": "http://example.com/ing2/villa-ortobene/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x-5/",
        "alt": "",
        "author": "1",
        "description": "",
        "caption": "",
        "name": "2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x-5",
        "status": "inherit",
        "uploaded_to": 128537,
        "date": "2019-06-28 09:42:38",
        "modified": "2019-06-28 09:42:47",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
        "type": "image",
        "subtype": "jpeg",
        "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
        "width": 515,
        "height": 482,
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x-150x150.jpg",
          "thumbnail-width": 150,
          "thumbnail-height": 150,
          "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x-200x187.jpg",
          "medium-width": 200,
          "medium-height": 187,
          "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x.jpg",
          "medium_large-width": 515,
          "medium_large-height": 482,
          "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-aspect-ratio-x.jpg",
          "large-width": "515",
          "large-height": "482"
        },
        "original_image": {
          "ID": 128299,
          "id": 128299,
          "title": "2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2",
          "filename": "2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2.jpg",
          "filesize": 55980,
          "url": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2.jpg",
          "link": "http://example.com/ing2/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2/",
          "alt": "",
          "author": "1",
          "description": "",
          "caption": "",
          "name": "2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2",
          "status": "inherit",
          "uploaded_to": 0,
          "date": "2019-03-03 17:12:57",
          "modified": "2019-03-03 17:12:57",
          "menu_order": 0,
          "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
          "type": "image",
          "subtype": "jpeg",
          "icon": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
          "width": 1000,
          "height": 667,
          "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-150x150.jpg",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-280x187.jpg",
            "medium-width": 280,
            "medium-height": 187,
            "medium_large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2-768x512.jpg",
            "medium_large-width": 768,
            "medium_large-height": 512,
            "large": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-03-03_5c7c0b184ec71_villa2.jpg",
            "large-width": "1000",
            "large-height": "667"
          }
        }
      },
      "codice_lavoro": "0F122",
      "id_opera": "EG09",
      "assegna_le_categorie": [
        {
          "nome_categoria": "Ingegneria",
          "costo": "275000"
        },
        {
          "nome_categoria": "Edilizia",
          "costo": "328000"
        }
      ],
      "tipologia_lavoro": "A01",
      "il_committente": [
        "Comune di sassari"
      ],
      "status": "In corso",
      "servizi": [
        "Progettazione"
      ],
      "anno": "2015",
      "mese": "1"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/128537"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
        }
      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
      ],
      "replies": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=128537"
        }
      ],
      "version-history": [
        {
          "count": 34,
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/128537/revisions"
        }
      ],
      "predecessor-version": [
        {
          "id": 128630,
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/128537/revisions/128630"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=128537"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "category",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=128537"
        },
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://example.com/ing2/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=128537"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the value of `anno`

I tried

```
var_dump($response["details"]["anno"]);
```

But I get `NULL`

Looks like the data is serialized, so I tried

```
$data = unserialize($response["details"]["anno"][0]);
```

And then

```
print_r($data);
```

But I get nothing. Basically I need to get the values of all those unserialized fields but I'm stacked.

Like the following which is serialized and I'd need to get the address or the coords

```
"location": [
        "a:3:{s:7:\"address\";s:95:\"Avinguda de la Granvia de l’Hospitalet, 8, 08902 L'Hospitalet de Llobregat, Barcelona, Spagna\";s:3:\"lat\";s:17:\"41.36256133817761\";s:3:\"lng\";s:17:\"2.131976960327165\";}"
      ],
```

Basically I need to be able to grab any simple data from `"details": {`

Comment: You have an array containing objects here, so you need to use the right syntax to access object properties in the appropriate places. `$response[0]->details` … etc.

Comment: you have tried with `myData[0].details.anno`  this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on your answers:

```php
$response = wp_remote_get(get_home_url()."2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=".$userPostsExternal);

$data = json_decode($response['body'], true);

var_dump($data[0]["details"]["anno"][0]);
```

Explanation:

`wp_remote_get` is the internal wordpress method as described here `https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get` 
It returns an array which contains the two elements: the HTTP response `headers` and `body`. The json data is in the `body` element. As the body is in json format you need to parse it using `json_encode` function. The second `true` argument defines that the parsed json string will be returned as array. The json data is an array which contains a single element, that's why you need to use the `$data[0]` to get the exact response data.

Comment: yes! that's working, could you please explain it a bit more? I have been struggling for 2 days

Comment: how would we get "collaboratori" and "partner" ? I tried echo $data[0]["acf"]["partner"]; but nothing and echo $data[0]["details"]["acf"]["partner"]; yet nothing

Comment: @rob.m try $data[0]["acf"]["collaboratori"] and $data[0]["acf"]["partner"]

Answer (score 1):

As per your answers, it seems that `$response` variable was holding response from `wp_remote_get` function call. It returned http request data - headers, body (etc.). Json itself was in `body` property of the original `$response`.

You need to use `json_decode` function.
First, decode json response. And then you can access its properties.

```
$jsonResponse = $response['body'];
$data = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
var_dump($data[0]['details']['anno'][0]);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "2015"
```

Comment: I get Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Can you do `print_r($response)` or `var_dump($response)` and add it to your question?

Comment: json response is too big, but if I do  try echo gettype($response);  I get array

Comment: could you paste the way you get the json loaded into php script?

Comment: $response = wp_remote_get(get_home_url()."2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=".$userPostsExternal);

Comment: That is _not_ JSON, that is the array containing the data structure wp_remote_get returns. The JSON data itself is in the `body` entry of that array.

Comment: @misorude yes Tom has answered with just that, gosh I was getting mad in regards, thanks

Comment: how would we get "collaboratori" and "partner" ? I tried echo $data[0]["acf"]["partner"]; but nothing and echo $data[0]["details"]["acf"]["partner"]; yet nothing – rob.m 1 min ago    Edit

Answer (score 0):

this is an array , to you have to point to the firt element at the index 0
try this  :

```
var_dump($response[0]["details"]["anno"][0]);
```

Comment: I still get NULL, I have updated the question with a more prettyfied json response if that helps

Comment: can you try now ?

Comment: I have but I get null

Comment: i followed the other answer but I get an error as per the comment I've given to that answer

Comment: what is the type of **$response** ? try echo **gettype($response);**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196467/discussion-between-rob-m-and-mohammed-yassine-chabli).

Comment: it says me "array"

Comment: @rob.m see my answer